# Jenkins build fail for PR from GitHub

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-github-plugin

I'm using jenkins pipeline to build my github project. When I raise a pull request (PR) on GitHub, its creating a job "pr-head"

[image: job screenshot]

which fails all the time with below error

[image: Error screenshot]

Let me know if you have any suggestions for this

Even the answers in [Git PullRequest job failed. Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906352/git-pullrequest-job-failed-couldnt-find-any-revision-to-build-verify-the-repo) did not solve my problem

Comment: Can you show your Jenkinsfile, please?

Comment: Please post the error message as text so your question may be found by possible future readers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git PullRequest job failed. Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906352/git-pullrequest-job-failed-couldnt-find-any-revision-to-build-verify-the-repo)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Update 2019/03/22:

### Quick anser

Use a refspec which fits your git server's PR handling. E.g. for Bitbucket that could be:

```
+refs/pull-requests/*/merge:refs/remotes/@{remote}/PR-*
```

## Full Answer

There is an open ticket about this:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52668?filter=18657

### EDIT:

I was able to reproduce this issue using a Jenkins multibranch pipeline together with the github plugin and a manual call to the `checkout` step.

For Bitbucket I found several options how to build PRs. I now even found a way to skip the conditional there. See below.

#### Recommendation

Whenever possible I'd recommend using `checkout scm` which works for PRs easily.

If you need to use the `checkout` step manually you could try to adjust your Jenkinsfile in order to do things manually as I did for checking out a bitbucket repo.

Easiest way should be to do a `checkout scm` at least one time to see how it should be done and use that values accordingly in the manual checkout steps. You'll need some if condition for the case that you're not building a PR.

---

## Github

I finally got my small sample project buildin PRs from github using the following code. For my quick test I did a PR from some branch. In case you're using a fork as source for the PR it may need some further adjustment.

As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36359706/4279361 you can leave out 'branches to build' option to not get this error. However depending on your PR merge strategy you'd still need to configure the merge accordingly:

```
def isPr() {
    env.CHANGE_ID != null
}

// github-specific refspec
def refspec = "+refs/pull/${env.CHANGE_ID}/head:refs/remotes/origin/PR-${env.CHANGE_ID} +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master"
def url = 'https://github.com/orgi/workflow-durable-task-step-plugin.git'

def extensions = []
if (isPr()) {
    extensions = [[$class: 'PreBuildMerge', options: [mergeRemote: "refs/remotes/origin", mergeTarget: "PR-${env.CHANGE_ID}"]]]
}

checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    extensions: extensions,
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
        refspec: refspec,
        credentialsId: '<your credentials>',
        url: url
    ]]
])
```

## Bitbucket

For bitbucket you have to do the almost the same. However you'll have the option to the merge commit done in bitbucket directly in which case you do not need to do the merge in Jenkins but need to switch to the PR branch instead.
You may either work with a conditional refspec or choose the branch conditionally. That makes four options a shown below. So far I didn't find an option which does not involve a conditional. :(

### Recommended solutions

Following solutions to me seems most usable. They do not involve any  conditionals and make use of the `BRANCH_NAME` variable. However it occurred to me that sometimes I got an error about an invalid refspec. In those cases please use one of the alternative solutions as written below.

#### Using Bitbucket Merge

Use the merge which as prepared by the Bitbucket server

```
def respec = '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull-requests/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/PR-*'
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: env.BRANCH_NAME]],
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
        refspec: respec,
        url: '<repo URL>'
    ]]
])
```

#### Using Jenkins Merge

Or you decide to let Jenkins do the merge. You may either use a conditional refspec or a conditional merge into the PR.

```
def refspec = '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull-requests/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/PR-*'
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    extensions: [[$class: 'PreBuildMerge', options: [mergeRemote: "refs/remotes/origin", mergeTarget: env.BRANCH_NAME]]],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
        refspec: refspec,
        url: '<repo URL>'
    ]]
])
```

#### Shared library

To use PR branches alongside a global shared library it would seem like the most straight-forward way would be to use the `Discover other refs` option when configuring the source control for your library. However that didn't work for me :(

[image]

To load a shared library from some pull request you have to do two things:

1. Add the following refspec to your shared library's Jenkins global configuration:

   ```
   +refs/pull-requests/*/merge:refs/remotes/@{remote}/PR-*
   ```
2. Instead of just using `env.BRANCH_NAME` you have to use`"origin/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"` when loading that library, like:

   ```
   libBranch = env.BRANCH_NAME
   libId= "myLib@origin/${libBranch}"
   lib = library(libId)
   ```

### Alternative Solution using Bitbucket Merge

#### Conditional Refspec

Just as a fallback; I can remember that the refspec including the PRs sometimes didn't work for me. In that case you could use:

```
def isPr() {
    env.CHANGE_ID != null
}

def respec = '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
if (isPr()) {
    respec += ' +refs/pull-requests/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/PR-*'
}
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: env.BRANCH_NAME]],
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
        refspec: respec,
        url: '<repo URL>'
    ]]
])
```

#### Conditional Branch Name

```
def isPr() {
    env.CHANGE_ID != null
}
def branch
if (isPr()) {
    branch = "refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/${env.CHANGE_ID}/merge"
} else {
    branch = "*/master"
}

checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: branch]],
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
        refspec: '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/*',
        url: '<repo URL>'
    ]]
])
```

### Alternative Solution using Merge in Jenkins

#### Conditional refspec

```
def isPr() {
    env.CHANGE_ID != null
}
def refspec = '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
if (isPr()) {
    refspec += ' +refs/pull-requests/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/PR-*'
}
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    extensions: [[$class: 'PreBuildMerge', options: [mergeRemote: "refs/remotes/origin", mergeTarget: env.BRANCH_NAME]]],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
        refspec: refspec,
        url: '<repo URL>'
    ]]
])
```

#### Conditional merge

```
def isPr() {
    env.CHANGE_ID != null
}
def extensions = []
if (isPr()) {
    extensions = [[$class: 'PreBuildMerge', options: [mergeRemote: "refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests", mergeTarget: "${env.CHANGE_ID}/from"]]]
}
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    extensions: extensions,
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
        refspec: '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/*',
        url: '<repo URL>'
    ]]
])
```

Comment: All these are invalid ref spec => +refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/* && +refs/pull-requests/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/* &&  +refs/pull-requests/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/PR-* && +refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/*

Comment: @Deunz: Wrong how?

Comment: No matter how, if I checkout using refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/* for instance I get some invalid specs error, apparently * are not supported for pull-requests

Comment: Using git command line, Jenkins pipeline git plugin or something else? Maybe you're running an older git version? Which git version do you use?

Comment: Using Jenkins pipeline git plugin on a bitbucket

Comment: This is working refspec: '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull-requests/197/from:refs/remotes/origin/PR-197'

The refspec uses the real PR number. If I replace 197 or whatever PR number it is by * then it's not working anymore

Comment: I can only assume that this is related to the git version. I suppose the error message is not useful either.