# How to build a Pipeline basic with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I try to use Pipeline script and I arrive until last step.

[image]

The Pipeline script is the following code

```
node{
  stage ('Build') {

    git url: 'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/01-eureka.git'

    withMaven(
        // Maven installation declared in the Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration"
        maven: 'M3',
        // Maven settings.xml file defined with the Jenkins Config File Provider Plugin
        // Maven settings and global settings can also be defined in Jenkins Global Tools Configuration
        mavenSettingsConfig: 'my-maven-settings',
        mavenLocalRepo: '.repository') {

      // Run the maven build
      sh "mvn clean install"

    } // withMaven will discover the generated Maven artifacts, JUnit Surefire & FailSafe & FindBugs reports...
  }
}
```

I have already been configured the maven and Java.

I don't know the error of the last step , I update all code.

Comment: Have you tried looking for similar errors, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906017/jenkins-build-fail-for-pr-from-github/51915362#51915362?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git PullRequest job failed. Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906352/git-pullrequest-job-failed-couldnt-find-any-revision-to-build-verify-the-repo)

Comment: How do you provide the password for you git user? Looks like jenkins wasn't properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exact ENV as your's, but first thing first, you should check the your Jenkins workspace folder Jenkins\workspace\docker-app, to see if the git clone works as expected

If the source code are there, manual run the maven command to see if Maven finds the pom.xml correctly