# Can't find revision on Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to build a NodeJS project via Jenkins pipeline. It is failing before it can process the first stage of the pipeline. Currently using Jenkins 2.249.2

Log:

```
Started by user woodsman@mycompany.com
Checking out git git@github.mycompany.com:MY-PROJECT/myproj-sprint-middleware.git into /var/jenkins_home/jobs/cirrus-sprint-middleware/workspace@script to read Jenkinsfile-test
using credential redcost_git
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.mycompany.com:MY-PROJECT/myproj-sprint-middleware.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.mycompany.com:MY-PROJECT/myproj-sprint-middleware.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Redcost (test.sl.redcloud.mycompany.com, /home/redcost/.ssh )
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@github.mycompany.com:MY-PROJECT/myproj-sprint-middleware.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/initial-port^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/initial-port^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision ad9133bac04efe906b011b0b6952a58ca6931595 (refs/remotes/origin/initial-port)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f ad9133bac04efe906b011b0b6952a58ca6931595 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Add Jenkinsfile-myproj"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
Loading library bitwiseman-shared@blog/declarative/notifications
Attempting to resolve blog/declarative/notifications from remote references...
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git ls-remote -h -- https://github.com/bitwiseman/jenkins-pipeline-shared # timeout=10
Found match: refs/heads/blog/declarative/notifications revision 723aa282fa5b5b9ac21ff0f4b1bda245ab21553c
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/bitwiseman/jenkins-pipeline-shared # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/bitwiseman/jenkins-pipeline-shared
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/bitwiseman/jenkins-pipeline-shared +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 723aa282fa5b5b9ac21ff0f4b1bda245ab21553c (blog/declarative/notifications)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 723aa282fa5b5b9ac21ff0f4b1bda245ab21553c # timeout=10
Commit message: "Added sendNotifications"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 723aa282fa5b5b9ac21ff0f4b1bda245ab21553c # timeout=10
Loading library slack-notifier-jenkins-sl@master
Attempting to resolve master from remote references...
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git ls-remote -h -- https://github.com/Gradiant/slack-notifier-jenkins-sl.git # timeout=10
Found match: refs/heads/master revision e4bc9d95d7266aa8cf9f96668d5ca781a6c9a2da
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Gradiant/slack-notifier-jenkins-sl.git # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Gradiant/slack-notifier-jenkins-sl.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/Gradiant/slack-notifier-jenkins-sl.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e4bc9d95d7266aa8cf9f96668d5ca781a6c9a2da (master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f e4bc9d95d7266aa8cf9f96668d5ca781a6c9a2da # timeout=10
Commit message: "Add contributing guidelines"
 > git rev-list --no-walk e4bc9d95d7266aa8cf9f96668d5ca781a6c9a2da # timeout=10
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on bcjenkins_slave_test in /home/bcjenkins/Taas_Jenkins/workspace/myproj-sprint-middleware
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] newArtifactoryServer
[Pipeline] newMavenBuild
[Pipeline] newBuildInfo
[Pipeline] slackSend
run slackstepsend, step false, desc false
Slack Send Pipeline step configured values from global config - baseUrl: true, teamDomain: false, token: true, channel: false, color: false
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /home/bcjenkins/Taas_Jenkins/workspace/myproj-sprint-middleware/Sprint_Middleware_test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout)
[Pipeline] git
using credential redcost_git
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.mycompany.com:MY-PROJECT/myproj-sprint-middleware.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.mycompany.com:MY-PROJECT/myproj-sprint-middleware.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Redcost (test.sl.redcloud.mycompany.com, /home/redcost/.ssh )
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@github.mycompany.com:MY-PROJECT/myproj-sprint-middleware.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] slackSend
run slackstepsend, step false, desc false
Slack Send Pipeline step configured values from global config - baseUrl: true, teamDomain: false, token: true, channel: false, color: false
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/proj-test^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/proj-test^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/proj-test^{commit} # timeout=10
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker image prune -f
Total reclaimed space: 0B
+ docker volume prune -f
Total reclaimed space: 0B
[Pipeline] slackSend
run slackstepsend, step false, desc false
Slack Send Pipeline step configured values from global config - baseUrl: true, teamDomain: false, token: true, channel: false, color: false
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

The Git branch I'm trying to build is initial-port.

For the "Branches to build" portion, I've tried these things:

- "*/initial-port"
- "/initial-port"
- A git parameter where I select origin/initial-port
- Copying the pipeline file directly into Jenkins rather than fetching it via SCM, and got the same result.
- Unchecking "Lightweight checkout"
- Following the suggestion at [Git PullRequest job failed. Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906352/git-pullrequest-job-failed-couldnt-find-any-revision-to-build-verify-the-repo) answered by @Tammytee, as best as I could understand. I put in refs/remotes/origin/initial-port instead of origin/initial-port.

I also tried a different branch git area: I want to use git@github.mycompany.com:MY-PROJECT/myproj-sprint-middleware.git, but tried git@github.mycompany.com:MY-PROJECT/other-project.git just to see if it works. It does at least build checkout the code and fetch the pipeline file.

I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I cannot tell what this error message really means. I can open a separate terminal and clone the repo that I specify, and checkout the branch that I'm asking for. The pipeline file exists in that branch. Indeed, I was able to see the repo in the Jenkins workspace.

I've looked at other similar postings, but didn't see one that either applied or worked.